# MATLAB function that returns the smallest prime number p<100,000 such that (p+n) is prime, where n is scalar integer and is the only input

Tags: matlab

I have this homework for a MATLAB Curse. I am 14 and I can't understand the problem perfectly, because my english skills. I would like some help with this problem. thank you in advance.

```
function pr=prime(n)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are not here to do your homework. Please add a [mcve] showing what you have done so far, why it is not working for you and what you want it to do.

Comment: I wouldn't call MATLAB a curse :)

Comment: @rayryeng I do curse a lot when trying to do things in MATLAB though :D

Answer (score 6):

If this is homework I wont give you the result, but just some ideas of how to get there.

You need a function `findmyprime()` that will return what you just described.

Example outputs: `findmyprime(2)` `>> 5` Because the first primes are `2 3 5 7 9 ..` and the first one where `p` and `p+n`are primes is 5 for n=2. See that 5 is prime and 5+2=7 is prime also.

I reccomend you have a look to the function [`primes()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/primes.html), that will get you started. Also, see [`find()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html?searchHighlight=find).

Comment: The function diff() may be helpful; or you should learn to use "for" loops.

Comment: Also have a look at `isprime` as well.  Combining this with `find` and `primes` should solve your problem.